# How to get DISPLAY environment variable when running cron

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron, environment-variables

My current effort has me creating a cron job (via editing /etc/crontab, **not** using the crontab -e command) in order to automatically execute a bash script that makes a series of sub-script calls that execute a test case in Robot Framework and then does some stuff with the results. (The call even sends standard output & errors to a log file!) I am running on Centos 7, and the cron job call looks something like this:

```
0  6  *  *  * service    BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc bash -lc /test/runTests.bash > /test/log/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M-\%S`_regression-test.log 2>&1
```

> *Some quick context for the uninitiated*: cron jobs will not run a login shell for their execution because they're supposed to be automatic; no reason to do the extra execution needed for a logged-in user. Because of this, commands executed via cron do *not* have any of the environment variables you might expect them to have. If you need environment variables during execution, you have to introduce them. There's a couple of ways to do it, some of which I've employed here:
>
> - Specify BASH_ENV, pointing it to a file that lists some environment variables.
> - Use the -l parameter in bash to explicitly specify a login shell, forcing bash to load environment variables.
>
>   - Note: this will not retrieve a user's .bashrc file, so that still needs to be specified if it contains environment variables that you need.
> - You can also export the environment variable directly in the crontab file or in the executable (I have not employed this method (yet))

Among the parameters available in Robot Framework, there is the option to include a "Listener" which will react to high-level occurrences during test execution. I want to run a Listener to capture some information, but there's a problem: running with a listener specified causes the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/RobotTests/listener.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/home/service/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/home/service/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 143, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
```

Now, I ran into an issue similar to this earlier in my efforts where I needed to do the extra legwork to specify environment variables for the cron and, as you can infer from my explanation up above, I have mostly sorted these issues out. Unfortunately, some of the variables fall through the cracks; in this case, the DISPLAY variable. This variable is not specified in any of the files imported by the shell, and certainly not by my .bashrc file. I'm not sure where, if at all, it is specified in my system and I would like to get a hold of the variable so I can execute this test properly.

Thus my question becomes: **How do I get the DISPLAY environment variable when running cron**? Also, for my knowledge: How does the DISPLAY environment variable get specified in general?

edit: And to clarify, this execution does not actually use a display. It just expects a DISPLAY variable to exist. The execution normally calls an instance of Firefox, but I have specified for it to run headless.

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* `DISPLAY` environment variable. You can run many (or zero) X sessions, each will have its own `DISPLAY`. Having a cron job that needs a display is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: You don't generally run interactive programs in `cron`.

Comment: If you aren't actually using an X11 server as a display, just set DISPLAY to anything, e.g. `export DISPLAY=:0.0`. Some programs that think they need X11 can be fooled by running `xvfb`, btw.

Comment: The `DISPLAY` var is set by your display manager (which doesn't exist for cron jobs) or SSH if X11 forwarding is enabled (also not applicable to cron jobs). Cron jobs should not require an interactive session with a tty or X11 display. Looking at https://github.com/asweigart/mouseinfo/blob/master/src/mouseinfo/__init__.py it is unlikely that simply doing `export DISPLAY=:0.0` will work. You'll probably need to use a mechanism such as `xvfb`.

Comment: Also, @remingtonhowell, what you're describing is running inherently interactive tests in a "headless" environment. I googled "robot framework cron" and got many useful answers; such as https://groups.google.com/g/robotframework-users/c/WaBPH0AKfTk.

Comment: @Mark-Setchell So I tried the export DISPLAY method and, as Kurtis Raider suggested, it did not work. The error specified that pyautogui wanted to connect to it and, because it was fake, it crashed again. I suspect I will need xvfb given the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: xvfb sounds like the solution to go with

Circumstances with my work have changed and I suspect I will be either creating a different listener component for my script or disregarding it entirely. But I'm going to put an answer here for posterity:

I attempted to use DISPLAY=:0.0 as Mark Setchell suggested, but it did not work. Although it resolved the issue of the non-existent environment variable, pyautogui still crashed because it actually expected it to be a real display. Given this, and having done some research into the subject, **I suspect running xvfb would be an effective workaround** since it is creating a virtual display to work with.

Unfortunately, I don't have it installed on the testing box and the hassle to get approval for it makes it less than ideal. Combine that with the fact that running cron means that there isn't much worth listening to and it isn't really worth the additional effort.